# Behaviour of fgetc on hitting '\n'

Tags: c, io

Heres the code I want to take input from the file and count number of characters in each line , but it stops at the first line itself

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
 FILE *instream; 
int c;
char in;
int linenum = 1; 
int charcount = 0;
   if ((instream = fopen("in.txt","r+")) == NULL) { 
      printf("Unable to open file3\n");
      return(0);
}
while ((c = fgetc(instream)) != EOF ){ 
if(c == '\n') {

   printf("%3d: %d\n",linenum,charcount); 
   linenum++;
   charcount = 0;
}

else{

      charcount++; 
  }
} 

  fclose(instream);
         }
```

Here is the file format

```
abcdef
mnopqr
```

And the out put

```
 1: 6
```

But what I expected was

```
 1: 6
 2: 6
```

How do I do this using getc?
I have seen many answers on getc behaving differently when encounters '\n' but they seem to be too different from what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not handle correctly the situation when the last line has no `'\n'` character at the end.

This is commonly handled by a conditional after the loop:

```
while ((c = fgetc(instream)) != EOF ){
    ...
}
// Handle the last line:
if (charcount != 0) {
    printf("%3d: %d\n", linenum, charcount); 
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes,I realised my mistake, this works , I could also have ended my file with a '\n'(i.e,hitting return) which I dint.